# Python 3: Join lines of file if its not endswith a special character

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Suppose a log file formatted like this:

> TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のevery message ends withの
>   TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のa message
>   that contains new-line character
>   even its still ends withの
>   TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のevery message ends withの
>   TIMESTAMPの[ERROR]のanother message
>   have new-line characters in itの
>   TIMESTAMPの[ERROR]のevery message ends withの

How can I display this file like this:

> TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のevery message ends withの
>   TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のa message 
>   that contains new-line character 
>   even its still ends withの
>   TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のevery message ends withの
>   TIMESTAMPの[ERROR]のanother message 
>   have new-line characters in itの
>   TIMESTAMPの[ERROR]のevery message ends withの

Comment: replace any newline with nothing it the character before newline is not の

Comment: try log.split("の\n"), I dont think you need a regex for a simple problem like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another (plain and not much *pythonic*) way:

```
>>> line_prefix = ''
>>> with open(r'your_file.log') as log_file:
        for line in log_file:
            if line.startswith('TIMESTAMPの'):
                print line_prefix
                line_prefix = line.strip()
            else:
                line_prefix += ' ' + line.strip()
        else:
            print line_prefix   

TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のevery message ends withの
TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のa message that contains new-line character even its still ends withの
TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のevery message ends withの
TIMESTAMPの[ERROR]のanother message have new-line characters in itの
TIMESTAMPの[ERROR]のevery message ends withの
```

Answer (score 3):

Just filter the lines and then use `join`.

```
import re
with open('log_file') as file:
    union = ''.join(filter(lambda line: re.match(r'\w+'), file.readlines()))
    # change the regex as per your definition of 'special characters'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your log file is `utf-8` encoded:

```
import re

with open('log.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f_log:
    print(re.sub(r'(\]の[^の]*の)', lambda x: x.group(1).replace('\n', ' '), f_log.read()))
```

Which would display:

```
TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のevery message ends withの
TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のa message that contains new-line character even its still ends withの
TIMESTAMPの[INFO]のevery message ends withの
TIMESTAMPの[ERROR]のanother message have new-line characters in itの
TIMESTAMPの[ERROR]のevery message ends withの
```

This works by spotting any `]のxxxxxxの` sequence (with or without newlines) and replacing any newlines with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to use a regex, but if you don't want, you can do something like this:

```
def concat_lines(input_file):
    s = ''
    for line in input_file:
        if not line.endswith('の\n'):
            s += line.replace('\n', ' ')
        else:
            s += line
            yield s
            s= ''
from pathlib import Path
with Path(<filename>).open('r') as in_file:
    for line in concat_lines(in_file):
        print(line)
```

or if you want to write it somewhere else:

```
with Path(<in_filename>).open('r') as in_file, Path(<out_filename>).open('r') as out_file:
    for line in concat_lines(in_file):
        out_file.write(line)
```